# How to define a new dataframe column based on multiple conditions in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some raw data in a data frame in R that I want to convert. Basically, I have a long format table of about 1000 observations and 4 variables with ID (identification of the individual), Question numbers (80 + in total), and answers as seen in this image [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Dt0.png). The questions are repeated for every individual in this format.

```
data <- data.frame(
    id = 1:10,
    Question = rep("Q1", 10),
    Answer = sample(5, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I want to create a new column based only on a selection of questions and give that column different values based on what the Answer value is.

So for example, if a row of interest has Answer = 5 my new column should have value 20. Those values have no specific relationship (mathematically) but they are not random (eg. 1 ~ 0, 2 ~ 1, 5 ~20). If the row is not of interest, then the value is NA (missing).

Expected output if the rows of interest are 2 and 5, assuming that the new column name is "new_values" and just for the sake of example, the rule is `new_values <- Answer * 4`

```
   id Question Answer new_values
1   1       Q1      4         NA
2   2       Q1      3         12
3   3       Q1      5         NA
4   4       Q1      3         NA
5   5       Q1      3         12
6   6       Q1      3         NA
7   7       Q1      2         NA
8   8       Q1      5         NA
9   9       Q1      2         NA
10 10       Q1      2         NA
```

Comment: It is essential to post a reproducible sample of your data set by means of `dput(head(data))` to have better chances of getting relevant answers and also a clear description of how your desired output would look like.

Comment: look into `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::recode` functions

Comment: I would do something like this :   `library(dplyr)
x <-seq(1,20)
y <- seq(10,29)
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

df <- df %>% mutate(newColumn  = ifelse(y > 20, x + y, x * y))
head(df)`

Comment: I like to do this with a look-up table: `lookup = data.frame(Answer = c(1, 2, 5), New_Column = c(0, 1, 20))` and then you can do a merge or left-join, `merge(old_data, lookup, by = "Answer")`.

Comment: I am sorry I missed that you saying no specific relationship, you could try this: `library(dplyr)
answer <-c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(5,10))
df <- data.frame(answer)

df <- df %>% mutate(newColumn  = ifelse(answer == 1, 0, ifelse(answer==2,1,20)))
`

Comment: @AbdurrahmanYavuz if you're using `dplyr`, this is a perfect time to use a single `case_when` rather than many nested `ifelse()`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I tried this but an  error comes up: df <- df %>%
+   mutate(newColumn = case_when(Answer == 1 ~ 0, 
+                                Answer == 2 ~ 1, 
+                                Answer == 3 ~ 2.5,
+                                Answer == 4 ~ 6, 
+                                Answer == 5 ~ 20,..... TRUE ~ Answer))                                                  Error  : Problem with `mutate()` input `newColumn`.
x must be a double vector, not an integer vector.
i Input `newColumn` is `case_when(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by defining which rows you are interested in and then performing the conditional definition for your new column. To define the rows you are interested in depends on what criteria you're using, which is a different matter.

To keep it simple, let's say you're interested in rows 2, 3 and 5. Define that as:

```
rows_of_interest <- c(2, 3, 5)
```

At first, we can define all new values as NA, so that the new column fits our dataframe.

```
data <- data.frame(
    id = 1:10,
    Question = rep("Q1", 10),
    Answer = sample(5, 10, replace = TRUE)
)

data$new_values <- NA
```

Then, we apply the conditions. You did not define explicitly how to convert `Answer` to `new_values`, but assuming it's a simple set of cases, you may want to define a function for that, just for the sake of clarity.

```
answer_to_new_values_converter <- function(answer) {
   if (answer < 2)
     return(answer + 5)
   if (answer > 3)
     return(answer * 4)
}
```

Now apply that to the column, but only on the rows we're interested in. We can do that by simple indexing.

```
data$new_values[rows_of_interest] <- answer_to_new_values_converter(data$Answer[rows_of_interest])
```

And that's it.